# Suspicious file under /usr/bin in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, performance, cpu

I have seen one of the process consuming 40% of the CPU. Up on check there is a file `/usr/bin/ujwjzppyff` running with "`grep -A`" command.

```
file /usr/bin/ujwjzppyff
/usr/bin/ujwjzppyff: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

Looks like this is `/usr/bin/ujwjzppyff` running suspicious. Any idea about this?

```
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      320351       1 48 Jun02 ?        5-06:03:39 grep "A"
root     3397125 3343766  0 06:01 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 320351
```

Comment: I sounds like you have some malware going on. You should kill the process and remove this file ASAP.

Comment: Code should only be installed via the software manager or apt. If installed from somewhere else your system is vulnerable

Comment: does `dpkg -S /usr/bin/ujwjzppyff` tell you which package the binary came from?

Comment: @kanehekili That's blatantly wrong.

Comment: @vidarlo - could you elaborate? I thought this is the basic idea of repositories. [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSoftware#Footnotes)

Comment: Yes, it makes maintenance easier, and it ensures interoperability. But Installing from other locations doesn't make your system vulnerable. Installing vulnerable pieces of software makes your system vulnerable, no matter what the source is. So your claim that installing from other sources makes a system vulnerable is a blatant misunderstanding of what Debian says. Also, only using official repos does not mean you have a secure system. There's more than software needed for that.

Comment: You can upload that file to https://www.virustotal.com/ to have its contents tested.